# Getting as much out of laptop on battery as on AC

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

Is it possible to get equal performance from a laptop when it's on battery (vs when it's on AC)? I'm running an object recognition application on my webcam feed, but the FPS drops 2-3 times on battery power, which is unacceptable. I'm using the high performance option under power options, but is it possible to keep the laptop from throttling my GPU?

Comment: Check `Control Panel` > `Power Options` > `Change plan settings` >  `Change advanced power settings` (you may also need to click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`). Have a look at the Processor Power Management settings when under battery power.

Comment: What's your laptop?  The GPU vendor's software may have its own power management options.  Also do what @sblair said.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that you're using Windows, **you need to disable power saving at *all three levels*: OS, GPU, and Hardware levels...**

1. Despite selecting High Performance in the Power Menu go into the advanced options and just turn off all the power saving features for the OS.
2. Then look to see if the GPU manufacturer has some additional settings.  [For example as shown here for ATI graphics cards.](https://superuser.com/a/96856/153054)
3. Lastly, go into the BIOS of the laptop and turn off any power saving features there.

Comment: Windows 7 is indicated in the tags.

Comment: Great answer!  I've taken the liberty to try to improve it a bit by adding a link and formatting the post.